# How to list the sub directory and the result load as an array component from groovy Jenkins script

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

```
def clusterComponent = "components/"

//from below listed the sub folder in components/ directory
         stage('list components') {
            sh("ls -A1 ${clusterComponent}")
        }
```

I want to load the list result to clustercomponent as an array.
example output should be clusterComponent = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]

maybe this is not the proper way. Still a beginner at groovy scripting.

Comment: The first method works for me. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the output of the `sh` step to a variable, you need to use `returnStdout: true`. Then you want to have each line of the output as a separate entry in the array/list, so you need to `.split('\n')` - split the string by the newline character.

The script can be:

```
def clusterComponent = "components/"

//from below listed the sub folder in components/ directory
stage('list components') {
    List<String> files = sh(script: "ls -A1 ${clusterComponent}", returnStdout: true).trim().split('\n')
}
```

You can also avoid the `sh` step to do this task and use the [findFiles](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace) step from pipeline-utility-steps. This returns a [FileWrapper](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/pipeline-utility-steps/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FileWrapper.html) class instance, so if you need the file name only, you can use:

```
def clusterComponent = "components/"

//from below listed the sub folder in components/ directory
stage('list components') {
    List<String> files = findFiles(glob: "${clusterComponent}/*").collect { file -> file.name }
}
```

Comment: The first method works for me. thank you so much!

Comment: Great, please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you